# How to use http client in an Akka actor that has a service?

Tags: scala, akka, executioncontext, akka-actor

I have an akka actor, and I would like to use a simple service inside that actor. That service should use [the client side api's](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html) singleRequest method to fetch something from the local network.

My Actor:

```
package actor

import actor.WorkerActor._
import akka.actor.Actor
import service.HealthCheckService

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object WorkerActor {
  case object HealthCheck
}

class WorkerActor extends Actor {

  implicit val system = context.system
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = context.system.dispatcher

  val healthCheckService = new HealthCheckService()

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case HealthCheck => sender ! healthCheckService.execute()
  }
}
```

Here I created an ActorSystem and an ExecutionContext as well, so that my service can use it:

```
package service

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse}

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

class HealthCheckService(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, implicit val system: ActorSystem) {


  def execute() = {
    val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://someRandom.url"))

    and do something with the response....
  }
}
```

If I don't pass an executionContext into the service I get the error:

```
[error] Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext. You might pass
[error] an (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) parameter to your method
[error] or import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.
```

And if I don't pass an actorsystem into the service I get the error:

```
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter system: akka.actor.ActorSystem
[error] val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://someRandom.url"))
```

**Questions:**

- How should services be correctly used from an Actor?
- Is it correct to pass around the ActorSystem and ExecutionContext, why doesn't it happen
  under the hood?

Comment: How are u making a call to an actor, where is the code for that ?

Answer (score 0):

`Http.apply` signature is

```
def apply()(implicit system: ActorSystem): HttpExt
```

so you need to pass `ActorSystem` to it implicitly or explicitly.
I do not see anything that requires ExecutionContext inside service, so suppose you do something with `Future` you get from `singleRequest` call. Any method on `Future` will require execution context.

So code is correct, but could be simplified a little:

```
class WorkerActor extends Actor {
  // you do not need to declare implicit val if you just need to pass it once
  val healthCheckService = new HealthCheckService(context.system)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case HealthCheck => sender ! healthCheckService.execute()
  }
}

class HealthCheckService(implicit val system: ActorSystem) {
  // dispatcher is already implicit so you need just import it, not declare another val
  import system.dispatcher
  def execute() = {
    val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://someRandom.url"))

    and do something with the response....
  }
}
```

Also, from your code for service I have an impression that you manipulate somehow with future, probably adding await (as soon as your service per your question does not really need `ActorSystem`), instead using akka and piping messages to actors from `Future`. Probably (as answer on you first question), you need to check later example of using `singleRequest` with actors from link to akka-http you added in question .